# Как установить модуль в nginx?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, freebsd

Здравствуйте.
Мне необходимо установить модуль `http_gzip_static_module`
FreeBSD 9.1
Nginx/1.4.2

Как это сделать? Читал, что поддержки модулей в виде библиотек, как, к примеру, в apache - в nginx нет. Нужно как то пересобирать/перекомпилировать из портов.
Я новичок в этих веб-серверах. Помогите доступно.

Answer (score 1):

nginx сервер не поддерживает динамически загружаемые модули расширения. Чтобы добавить модуль к nginx, нужно полностью компилировать nginx из исходных кодов с включенным и статически интегрированным в него новым модулем.

Если вы используете ports, то команда `port variants nginx` даст вам варианты сборки nginx и команда `sudo port -v install nginx +gzip_static +image_filter +zip +ssl +secure_link` установит и нужный вам http_gzip_static_module

То же самое можно сделать вручную - загрузите сборку исходных кодов nginx и нужных вам модулей, выполните

1. `cd nginx-версия`
2. `./configure --prefix=путь-для-установки-nginx --add-module=путь-к-модулю1 --add-module=путь-к-модулю2`
3. `make`
4. `make install`